# Transformation of Christoffel symbols

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

In Euclidean spaces, Christoffel symbols can be defined as components of $\frac{\partial \vec{X_i}}{\partial x^j}$ with respect to covariant basis, where $\vec{X}_i$ is covariant basis, that is:

\begin{align*}\Gamma_{ij}^k &= \frac{\partial \vec{X}_i}{\partial x^j}\cdot\vec{X}^k\end{align*}

With thus defined symbol, it is quite straightforward to show that under coordinate transformation, it transforms as:

\begin{align}
  \Gamma_{i'j'}^{k'} &= \frac{\partial \vec{X}_{i'}}{\partial x^{j'}}\cdot\vec{X}^{k'} = J^i_{i'}J^j_{j'}J^{k'}_k\Gamma^k_{ij} + J^{k'}_i\frac{\partial J^i_{i'}}{\partial x^{j'}}\\
&=J^i_{i'}J^j_{j'}J^{k'}_k\Gamma^k_{ij} + J^{k'}_iJ^i_{i'j'}
\end{align}

I am using the notation where primed are the new coordinates and unprimed are the old ones, also, $J^i_{j'}$ and $J^{i'}_{j}$ are corresponding mutually inverse Jacobians of the coordinate transformation, that is :

\begin{align*}
  J^i_{j'} &= \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^{j'}}\,,\text{ and}\\
  J^i_{i'j'} &= \frac{\partial J^i_{i'}}{\partial x^{j'}}= \frac{\partial^2 x^i}{\partial x^{j'}\,\partial x^{i'}}\,.
\end{align*}

And $\vec{X}^i$ are the basis vectors and $x^i$ are coordinates.

However, one can view other symbols as components of $\frac{\partial \vec{X}^i}{\partial x^j}$ with respect to the corresponding contravariant basis and it turns out that these symbols are negative of Christoffel symbols:

\begin{align*}
  \Gamma^i_{jk} &= - \frac{\partial \vec{X}^i}{\partial x^j}\cdot \vec{X}_k
\end{align*}

Now, when I calculate how this thing changes, I expect to get the same formula as asbove but I get:

\begin{align*}
  \Gamma^{i'}_{j'k'} &= - \frac{\partial \vec{X}^{i'}}{\partial x^{j'}}\cdot \vec{Z}^{k'} = -\left( J^{i'}_i J^j_{j'} \frac{\partial \vec{X}^i}{\partial x^j} + J^j_{j'} J^{i'}_{ij}\vec{X}^i  \right) \cdot \left(\vec{X}_k J^k_{k'}\right) \\
  &= J^{i'}_i\, J^j_{j'}\, J^k_{k'}\,\Gamma^i_{jk} - J^{i'}_{ij}\,J^j_{j'}\,J^i_{k'}
\end{align*}

Is that correct? How do I make the second term correspond to the second term in the calculation from the covariant basis?

**Note**: I specifically want to use these definitions, not the definition that is used in GR or in Riemann geometry that employs the derivatives of the metric tensor.

Comment: Should $Z$ be $X$?

Comment: @Deane Yes, i corrected it

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the change of basis matrix for the covariant basis (of tangent vectors) and its dual (contravariant) basis is the same as the Jacobian matrix for the change of coordinates. But this does not hold in general. Perhaps you omitted an assumption you are making for the covariant basis?

Comment: @Deane I am starting to learn tensor calculus from Grinfeld's book, He shows the change of basis through Jacobi matrix and it looked quite general. So, that begs a question, in what cases is that not true?

Comment: I am curious about why you chose this book. I find the notation to be quite confusing. I also see that you have tried to change the notation from $\mathbf{Z}$ to $\vec{X}$. Why did you choose to do that?

Comment: @Deane He has accompanying youtube videos which sometimes help, sometimes not and I did not know of any other book, it can be difficult to see if a book is good or not. I changed the notation because some people are not comfortable with the $\mathbf{Z}$ notation, i hoped, it would help... Also, i had introduction into tensors in my algebra but it was way to abstract for me to be able to apply it (it started by introducing dual spaces etc.). Also the calculus part was really missing there, then i had SR and GR but that was just a quick primer to be able to get used to it...

Comment: @Deane Just to continue, Grinfeld introduces Christoffel symbols very naturally, as components of $\partial_j\mathbf{Z}_i$ wrt covariant basis while in GR we introduced them by an identity regarding the metric tensor. The first approach while less general, is more illustrative for me. Anyway, I guess I understood some content of his YT videos thus i opted for the book to save time on watching the videos.

Comment: What you omitted is that $Z_1, \dots, Z_n$ are defined in terms of the coordinates $x^1, \dots, x^n$. That is why the Jacobian is the change of variable matrix for the covariant basis (we usually call it a frame).

Comment: @Deane Aren't $Z_i$ defined as $\frac{\partial \mathbf{R}}{\partial x^i}$ with $\mathbf{R}$ being the position vector, that is aren't the coordinates the requirement to be able to define basis vectors (be it in space or its dual)?

Comment: You did not define your notation and say that $Z_i$ is the partial derivative of the position vector with respect to $x^i$. I guess there's no way you could have known that Grinfeld is using his own nonstandard notation. I've now taken a look at the book. Grinfeld's approach is very old-fashioned, and, in my opinion, not the best or most beautiful way to learn this subject. What is your ultimate goal? Not general relativity?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\E{\mathbb{E}}\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\ov}[1]{\overline{#1}}$Let's use Grinfeld's notation and review whats going on. Let $\E$ be a Euclidean vector space, i.e., a vector space with a dot product. Let $\E^*$ be the dual vector space. Given $V \in \E$ and $\ell \in \E^*$, we use the notation
$$
\langle \ell, v\rangle
$$
to denote the value of the function $\ell$ with input $V$ (recall that an element of $\E^*$ is a linear function $\ell: \E \rightarrow \R$.

We start with an injective map $R: O \rightarrow \E$, where $O \subset \R^n$ is an open domain and an element of $O$ is denoted $(x^1, \dots, x^n)$. Let
$$
Z_i = \partial_iR\text{, where }\partial_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}.
$$
We assume that, for each $x \in O$, $(Z_1(x), \dots, Z_n(x))$ is a basis of $\E$. It has a dual basis of $\E^*$, which Drinfeld denotes by $(Z^1(x), \dots, Z^n(x))$. By definition,
$$
\langle Z^i(x),Z_j(x)\rangle = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{ if }i=j\\
0 &\text{ if }i \ne j \end{cases}.
$$

Now suppose we have another coordinate map, which we can call
$$
\ov{R}: \ov{O} \rightarrow \E,
$$
where we denote the new coordinates by $(\ov{x}^1, \dots, \ov{x}^n)$ and the corresponding frame by
$$
\ov{Z}_i = \frac{\partial \ov{R}}{\partial \ov{x}^i}.
$$
The dual frame will be denoted $(\ov{Z}^1, \dots, \ov{Z}^n)$.

The Jacobians will be denoted
$$
J^i_j = \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial\ov{x}^i}\text{ and }\ov{J}^i_j = \frac{\partial\ov{x}^i}{\partial x^j}.
$$

The Christoffel symbol is defined here to be
$$
\Gamma^k_{ij} = \langle Z^k, \partial_jZ_i\rangle.
$$
Since $\partial_jZ_i = \partial^2_{ij}R = \partial_iZ_j$,
$$
\Gamma^k_{ij} = \Gamma^k_{ji}.
$$

Differentiating $\langle Z^k,Z_i\rangle$, we get
$$
0 = \langle \partial_jZ^k,Z_i\rangle + \langle Z^k,\partial_jZ_i\rangle = 
\langle \partial_jZ^k,Z_i\rangle + \Gamma^k_{ij}.
$$
Therefore,
$$ \Gamma^k_{ij} = -\langle \partial_jZ^k,Z_i\rangle.
$$

At this point, I think you know how to proceed. But post more questions if you get stuck again.

It is also worth nothing that the dot product is not used at all. My guess is that Grinfeld used the dot product where I used the dual vector space. In the long run, I consider this to be much less confusing.